# Hibernate: BigInteger vs Long from native query to be used in JPQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, drools, jpql

In our Java EE EJB application, we have the following JPA/Hibernate mapping of a class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T")
@TableGenerator( /* all annotation attributes */)
public class T {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name="SEQ_T", nullable = false)
    private long seqT;

    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        orphanRemoval = true,
        mappedBy = "t",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<W> wu;

}
```

and these are the classes which are in relation with it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="W")
@TableGenerator( /* all annotation attributes */)
public class W {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name="SEQ_W", nullable = false)
    private long seqW;

    @Column(name="SEQ_T", nullable = false)
    private long seqT;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SEQ_T", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private T t;

    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        orphanRemoval = true,
        mappedBy = "w",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<WA> wua;
 }

@Entity
@Table(name="WA")
@TableGenerator( /* all annotation attributes */)
public class WA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name="SEQ_W_A", nullable = false)
    private long seqWA;

    @Column(name="SEQ_W", nullable = false)
    private long seqW;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SEQ_W", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private W w;

}
```

Moreover, we have a scheduled job which is executed periodically by `TimerService` EJB. 
First of all, this job must understand if there is something to execute so it performs a **native sql query** like the following to recover a list of pk from T table according several conditions:

```
List<Long> seqTs = (List<Long>)em.createNativeQuery("select SEQ_T from T").getResultList();
```

where `em` is an instance of `EntityManager`. The query is not obviously that simple but very complex as it derives from some `JOIN` and subqueries with other tables. 
If the returned list is not empty, then the job can do its work and this JPQL is performed to load the entities it manipulates:

```
String queryJPQL = "select wu from W wu JOIN FECTCH wu.wua where wu.seqT in :seqTs";
List<Workup> wus = em.createQuery(queryJPQL, W.class)
                     .setParameter("seqTs", seqTs)
                     .getResultList();
```

This query is performed because even if we always need the data in `@OneToMany` relation, if we set that relation as `EAGER` then N+1 queries is performed. Instead, with `JOIN FETCH` a unique query is performed recovering a sort of view and then entities and relations are associated by Hibernate.

Well, the problem is that this exception is raised when `.setParameter()` is called:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]

Reading many posts here, and set a breakpoint in Eclipse, I discovered that not a `List<Long>` is returned from a native query but a `List<BigInteger>` (according to native type of PK in database), without any `ClassCastException` or similar. Why this?
So, I guess I should perform something like this before:

```
List<Long> seqTLong = new ArrayList<Long>();
for(BigInteger seqNative : seqTs) 
        seqTLong.add(seqNative.longValue());
```

and pass it to the query.
Anyway, is this the right solution? Is it safe? This because our application supports 3 DB and it is built accordingly in 3 JARs by ANT: Oracle, PostgreSQL and SQL Server.
Can I assume the value of PK is always `BigInteger` for each DB? In Oracle we use `Number(19)`, in PostgreSQL we use `BigInt`...I don't remember about SQL Server. 
This entities are then passed to DRools and when rules have been applied, this job uses `EntityManager` to persist data. That's why I need JPA entities to be loaded, otherwise I would get a

> Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

or I would have to call  `.find()` again for each fact modified by DRools and set its attributes by calling getters from the others. Which still causes N+1 queries.

Comment: Disclosure: it's been a while... Your proposal to convert from `BigInteger` to `Long` looks right.  There may be some alternatives: you might try using `createNativeQuery("...", Long.class)`.  There maybe somethings to explore here as well: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-native-queries/

Comment: Yea, no.  I don't think you can pass in `Long.class`, it wants an entity.  You might explore using a JPA query up front instead of a native query, to leverage it's knowledge of return types to obtain results.  Without seeing your full flow, I'd suggest that the initial query "to see if there's work to do" may be unnecessary - just query for the WU's that meet your requirements (existence of a T? a simple JOIN).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yeah, I know I cannot pass Long.class or it would throw something like “Not an entity Exception”. Unfortunately that initial query is necessary and strictly required by my Product Owner. Not only because the other already existing jobs in our product do that (even if they have the N+1 queries problem, which now we would like to avoid by using JOIN FETCH). But also because, maybe in future, this new job could become multithreaded so main thread will distribute PKs to other threads to do their work. But, is BigInteger a safe type for each DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A safer method would be to use `Number` instead of `BigInteger`

```
List<Long> seqTLong = new ArrayList<Long>();
for(Number seqNative : seqTs) {
        seqTLong.add(seqNative.longValue());
}
```

Comment: For the moment it seems to work, I hope so. Anyway it seems that BigInteger si supported both for BigInt in Postgresql and for Numeric(19) in Oracle/SQL server. Anyway, I will use Number as you suggest and I hope not to have problems. Thank you for your answer